# Xcode Unit Testing with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods, xctest

I've been banging my head against a wall with this for the last few days but despite multiple Google/SO/Github searches I can't find a resolution to the issues I'm having!

All I'm trying to do is create some unit tests for my app which makes use of Firebase pods.

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 & Cocoapods 1.0.1. **Update:** Issue remains with Xcode 8.0

With this podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'

    target 'MyAppTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end
end
```

In my XCTest class I get

> Missing required module 'Firebase'

error at `@testable import MyApp`

Alternatively with this podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

def common_pods
    pod 'SwiftyTimer'
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    common_pods
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
    common_pods
end
```

The tests build but my console is littered with warnings e.g.:

> Class <-FirebaseClassName-> is implemented in both ...MyApp... and
>   ...MyAppTests... One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Comment: I was only using Firebase Analytics. After Moving to Google analytics everything works like a charm.

Comment: I haven't tried his myself yet but I might attempt to include Firebase manually not using cocoa pods: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

Comment: This is still an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for me was to update cocoapods to version 1.1.0.rc.2.

`sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me...I have to take back my upvote!

Comment: Sorry it didn't help you out guys, not sure why it solved the problem for me and not you...

Comment: I am on 1.20 and no luck

Answer (score 96):

I had the same issue. I solved it by moving `pod 'Firebase'` to my test target. Change your Podfile to this:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'

    target 'MyAppTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod 'Firebase'
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I just tried that and I still have the "Class ... is implemented in both ... " issue.

Comment: It worked for me but it still doesn't make sense to me. It's not the 1st time I can tell Firebase are setting up their podspecs weirdly, cf. https://twitter.com/dirtyhenry/status/836240557311684608 but the Firebase team doesn't reply :(

Comment: Making this change didn't immediately clear the warning, but it was resolved after I ran `pod install`.

Comment: Half problem solved. and other half is solved by Add "${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/Core/Sources" to your Tests target only under Build Settings -> Header Search Paths

Comment: After you make this change do not forget to run `pod install` in order to update project dependencies ;)

Comment: @Mackarous how do we achieve similar functionality with 'Swift Package Manager'

Answer (score 64):

Try changing the inheritance to `:complete`, as in:

```
target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
end
```

Importantly it allows anyone else checking out your repo to just do a `pod update` as usual without having to copy `.xcconfig` files or other hackery just to build.

Comment: This also have the "Class ... is implemented in both ... " issue

Comment: It made the compile time error disappear, but caused this one at runtime: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Worked for me as well! Thanks :)

Answer (score 62):

1. Select your Unit Test Target setting.
2. Go to Build Settings.
3. Look for Header Search Paths.
4. Add this value `$(SRCROOT)/Pods` with recursive, then Xcode will resolve the path for you.

Here is [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jIQY.png)

Comment: Thank you @Kanika Sharma

Answer (score 35):

The issue is that Firebase does something special with the Header Search Paths after CocoaPods generates its own value for the setting so CocoaPods doesn't pick up on this change in order to carry it over to the test target. You can solve this one of two ways:

1. Locate `MyAppTests.<configuration>.xcconfig` in the file navigator and add the following to `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`:

   `${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/Analytics/Sources` [*]
2. Find the setting for **Header Search Paths** in Build Settings and add that same value as in option 1 to the list. You shouldn't need to set it as recursive.

<sub>* As per AKM's comment, this changed to `${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/Core/Sources` in version 3.14.0</sub>

Comment: Tried that but still getting same warnings

Comment: As of Firebase 3.14.0 This solution is valid, however the patch changed to`${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/Core/Sources`

Comment: New path worked for me as well! I'm running CocoaPods *version 1.2.0*, but keep in mind I also had to add `inherit! :search_paths` to the test target in the `Podfile`.

Comment: 2. does not work for me. Using Firebase 3.x (not the newest 4.x)

Comment: Issue can be followed here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/58

Comment: Half Problem solved and in other half include pod 'Firebase' in test target.

Answer (score 10):

Adding `${SRCROOT}/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources` into the unit test target's "Header search paths" fixed the problem.
Steps:

1. Select your **unit tests target**
2. Go to **Build Settings**
3. Search for **header search path**
4. Add **${SRCROOT}/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources**

[image]

After this the tests can run and the error will disappear.

Comment: This is what worked for me. No need to touch podfile or xcconfig. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 9):

Three Steps before I could get this to work:

CocoaPods : 1.5.0
Swift 4
Firebase : 4.13.0

Step 1: 
Make sure to add the following target block into your podfile.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.3'

target 'TIMII' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for TIMII
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'

    target 'TIMIITests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod 'Firebase/Core'
    end

end
```

Step 2:
Within the YourAppTests Project Navigator Build Settings tab. Find the Header Search Path row and add to Debug the following line

> $(inherited) ${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/Core/Sources

Step 3:
In terminal run:

> pod update

Comment: Prefer `pod install` over `pod update`  unless you explicitly want to update your pods.
Docs: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html

Comment: This answer really helped me. Thanks. Other ways from this post did not work for me.

Answer (score 9):

A simpler method that also works:

```
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'

    target :MyAppTests
end
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. Any documentation on the syntax? What does `: MyAppTests` mean?

Comment: This works for me as well, and syntax looks the simplest!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is recorded in the firebase project here:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/58

There is a workaround:

> Add "${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/Core/Sources" to your Tests target only
>   under Build Settings -> Header Search Paths

but this is also fixed by upgrading to CocoaPods 1.4.0 or later, which is a better solution.

At the time I'm writing this (November 2017) cocoapods 1.4.0 is still in beta, so to install it you need to explicitly request the beta:

```
gem install cocoapods --pre
```

This and then doing a `pod install` solved the problem running my tests.

Comment: what is it "PODS_ROOT" ??

Comment: @ArgaPK It's a variable that cocoapods sets. Just paste exactly what I wrote between the ""s into Xcode. Really the best way is to upgrade your CocoaPods to >= 1.4.0.

Comment: @JosephH updating my cocoapods to 1.5.2 didn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @AnastasiaKovaleva did you run `pod install` after upgrading?

Comment: @JosephH  Running `pod install` solved my problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I tried all the above and ran into various different errors, originally starting with `Missing required module 'Firebase'`, then getting `"Class ... is implemented in both ... "` or linker issues if I tried to add Firebase Pods to my test target.

The solution that worked for me was to:

1. Remove test target entirely from Podfile and run 'pod update' to ensure the XCode project is in sync.
2. Open my test target's Build Settings and update header search paths to only include the following 3 items:

   - `$(inherited) non-recursive`
   - `$(SRCROOT)/Pods/Headers/Public recursive`
   - `$(SRCROOT)/Pods/Firebase recursive`

At this point cleaning the build folder, re-building then re-running the tests worked for me. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Phrased in terms of your question, I copied the contents of my `MyApp.<configuration>.xcconfig` file to my `MyAppTests.<configuration>.xcconfig` file. I cleaned and built the tests, and it worked.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks! I'm thinking about do a post install processing in the Podfile doing this

Answer (score 1):

Add **"${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/Core/Sources"** to your Tests target only under 
**Build Settings** -> **Header Search Paths**

Comment: What is it ? PODS_ROOT

Comment: it will fetch directory for pod

Answer (score 1):

As [@Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287550/will) mentioned an issue around **Header Search Paths** after CocoaPods installation.

I have a project with multiple targets where pod 'Firebase' embedded into separate module, lets say `MyProject-Shared`. Firebase pod at 'Podfile' installed only for 'MyProject-Shared' target.  Other modules, which wants to use 'MyProject-Shared' can't be compiled due an error:

'missing required module "Firebase" '

The trick in my case was to add following missing header search path at **each** target's **Build Settings** referencing to *Analytics-Framework*:

`"${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources"`

Please see pic below:
 [image: Header Search Path]

Hope it will save your time.

Answer (score 0):

## `Missing required module Firebase` NO CocoaPods solution

For those who encounter the same problem but NOT using CocoaPods:

If you're using Firebase, than you have some folder containing `Firebase.h` and `module.modulemap` file. For example - `YOUR_PROJECT_DIR/Linking`

If your Main project target is working correct way, than you should go to ProjectSettings -> Targets. Select test target. Search for `User headers` and add the path to `YOUR_PROJECT_DIR/Linking`. Select `recursive` option and you should be good to go.

See the screenshot for more details:

[image]