# 'Missing required module Firebase' - Import static library in a Dynamic Framework

Tags: swift, firebase, static-libraries

I have a Dynamic Framework X, this framework uses the Firebase SDK manually imported (static libraries).

I also have a normal iOS project Y, that contains the framework X as embedded binary.
X is imported into the AppDelegate.swift of Y project.

```
import X
```

Here I receive this error: ***'Missing required module Firebase'***

How is it possible? There is some specific procedure to setup Firebase static libraries in the framework?

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Did you figure this out?

Comment: @William Grand Please, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57870350/7388630